# Force underline on ALL links in Chrome/Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, website, web, chromium

I just saw a website where links and text have the exact same damn color and style. I had to literally "feel around" with my mouse cursor to find links. This just **isn't** accessible for people who've got even the *slightest* visual impairment.

So, how do I force-underline **all links** on a website from within Chrome/ium?

Note: I am already aware of and use the [high contrast extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/high-contrast/djcfdncoelnlbldjfhinnjlhdjlikmph) on a daily basis. It failed me at that time since the text/link colors were identical.

Comment: Fun game: "Find the links!" Open [this](https://i.imgur.com/Pk639L0.png) in paint and circle the links. Check your answers [*here!*](https://i.imgur.com/Gizv6Vg.png)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to get an extension called "Force Underline" from the chrome webstore.

[Force Underline logo / icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiIQk.jpg)

The extension can be found at: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/force-underline/mailocoigbmikldobfkikagehcoficho/related?hl=en

It works quite well and underlines all links on a page. The only links I've found it to not underline are the large headings of search results from the google.com website. All other links on google.com are however underlined.

P.S. I have no ties or affiliations with the author of this extension and I just happened to come across it because I was in search of the same feature.

Comment: Welcome, it's obligatory to declare if you have any associations with the author of the extension.

Comment: No, I do not know any authors of any extensions. I was actually looking for the same thing, ie to force Google Chrome to underline all links on a page when I came across this question and was hoping to find an answer myself.

After being fortunate enough to stumble upon a suitable solution, I came back to answer this question.

Cheers.

Comment: You should edit the answer and put the declaration in it.  I have upvoted it.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Thanks for the upvote.

Comment: I have since stopped using Chrome/Chromium so won't test this answer...